# BackButton cannot be handled in ContentDialog

Tags: button, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there a way to get any event raised while having a `ContentDialog` opened and the hardware/software BackButton of the device is pressed?

Comment: for what exactly do u want this ? The purpose for wanting such functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the back button while a ContentDialog is open will not raise the Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.BackRequested event.

It will, however, close the ContentDialog, and that will fire the ContentDialog's Closing and Closed events, in that order.  Also, the ContentDialog.ShowAsync() will return "None" if closed via the back button.  The below example demonstrates all three methods.

```
var cd = new ContentDialog() {
    Title = "Test Dialog",
    Content = "This is a test content dialog.  Hit the back button now.",
    PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
};
cd.Closing += (ContentDialog s, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs ev) => { new MessageDialog("Event 1 fired.").ShowAsync(); };
cd.Closed += (ContentDialog s, ContentDialogClosedEventArgs ev) => { new MessageDialog("Event 2 fired.").ShowAsync(); };
var result = await cd.ShowAsync();
if (result == ContentDialogResult.None)
{
   new MessageDialog("Back button was pressed.").ShowAsync();
}
```

Hope that helps!  If not, let me know.  :)

**UPDATE:**
Another solution I thought of is to handle the closing event by canceling it and adding whatever behavior you'd like.  This stops the ContentDialog from closing.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cd = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "Test Dialog",
        Content = "This is a test content dialog.  Hit the back button now.",
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
    };
    cd.Closing += Cd_Closing;
    await cd.ShowAsync();
}

private void Cd_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Result == ContentDialogResult.None)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        // Handle back press here instead of closing.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this solution, Jared. I did this already as a test, but it is not working when you have 2 or 3 buttons in that dialog(which have to return a proper result). +1 for the workaround, but unfortunately it won't help me much. The back button has to be functional only inside the dialog, which is wizard-like.